# Typescript - Filter does not work on arrays of union types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here are my type definitions:

```
export const APPLE = "apple"
export const PEAR = "pear"
export const PLUM = "plum"

export type TAllowedFruits = APPLE | PEAR | PLUM
...

export interface IGroceryCart {
    Fruits : TAllowedFruits,
    Veggies : TAllowedVeggies,
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I am specifying a union type that allows for fruit to either be apple, pear, or plum.

Somewhere else in my code, I now have an array of grocery carts lined up and for each cart, I want to filter out apples from their fruits and only show pears and plums on the UI.

So I do have like this:

```
const groceryCarts: IGroceryCart[] = getGroceryCarts()

groceryCarts.filter(cart => cart.Fruits !== APPLE).map(item => ...)
```

However, my UI is still showing all three fruits instead of just pears and plums. If I do this:

```
groceryCarts.filter(cart => cart.Fruits !=='apple').map(item => ...)
```

Then, the filter appropriately happens.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Also, forgive the contrived example but it's the best I could do to get the point across.

Comment: `filter` *returns* data, it does not change the array that it was invoked on (so if your map has *side effects*: 1st, don't do that. Map is for returning transformed data, 2nd we don't know what you are doing)

Comment: TypeScript does not infer type guard functions for you; at best you could manually annotate the callback as being such a type guard like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgrg6W).